# ListView onItemClick to ViewPager

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-listview, android-viewpager

I have a `ListView` and when the user click on one item , a `ViewPager` should open with the same title.So if Item 1 was clicked on , a `ViewPager` page with the same title should open, like in the image(on the left side). Also the pages should be swipe able but they must be in the same row as the `ListView` like in the image(on the right side).
How is it possible to do that? 
The `OnItemClick` method I have implemented already but what should I do now?

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

        }

    });
```

[image: ViewPager]

Comment: I think we need to see more code.

Comment: I need informations how to make it, I don't have more code.

Comment: I think you need to Google for tutorial and sample code

Comment: Do you have some examples? I don't find anything..